# How does C treat the number 0 in a one’s complement architecture?

Tags: c, ones-complement

I have recently been studying the one’s complement system of representing numbers and from what I understand there are two variants of the number 0. There is a negative zero (-0) and a positive zero (+0).

My question is, on a one’s complement architecture, how exactly is this anomaly treated in C? Does C make a distinction between -0 and +0 or are both of these forms simply treated as zero.

If it is the case that both +0 and -0 return TRUE when tested for zero, then I am wondering how the following sample code would work that calculates the number of set bits in an integer if we enter -0 as its input.

```
int bitcount(int x)
{
    int b;
    for (b = 0; x != 0; b++)
        x &= (x-1);
    return b;
}
```

Since -0, in one’s complement, has all of its bits set to 1, -0 should return the highest amount of bits set out of any other number; however, it appears that this code would fail the loop test condition of `x != 0`, and would not even enter the loop, giving an incorrect result.

Would it be possible somehow in C, in a one's complement architecture, to make the loop condition sensitive to positive zeros as in: `x != +0` Also, if I would subtract 1 from +0, would I get -0, or -1. In other words, does +0 - 1 = -0 in a one’s complement architecture?

All in all, not to go too far off course in this discussion, I am just wondering how C treats the peculiarities of the number 0 in a one’s complement architecture.

Comment: `0 - 1` isn't negative zero with one's complement, because that would be insane. =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is implementation-defined whether, on a ones-complement architecture, the value "with sign bit and all value bits 1" is a "trap representation" or a normal value.  If it is a trap representation, any attempt to do *anything* with it, or even create it in the first place, provokes undefined behavior.  If it is a normal value, it is a "negative zero", and there is an explicit list of operations that are allowed to produce it:

> If the implementation supports negative zeros, they shall be generated only by:
>
> - the &, |, ^, ~, <<, and >> operators with operands that produce such a value;
> - the +, -, *, /, and % operators where one operand is a negative zero and the result is zero;
> - compound assignment operators based on the above cases.
>
> It is unspecified whether these cases actually generate a negative zero or a normal zero, and whether a negative zero becomes a normal zero when stored in an object.

(C11/N1570, section 6.2.6.2 paragraph 3.)

It also appears to be unspecified (by omission) whether negative zero compares equal to normal zero.  Similar rules apply to sign-and-magnitude architectures.

So, what this boils down to is, the behavior of your example code is implementation-defined, and the implementation may not define it helpfully.  You would need to consult the compiler and architecture manuals for this hypothetical ones-complement machine to figure out whether it does what you want it to do.

However, the entire question is moot, because nobody has manufactured a non-twos-complement CPU in at least 25 years.  One hopes that a future revision of the C standard will cease to allow for the possibility; it would simplify many things.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I was curious how this worked, but I guess I won't have to worry about this in real life since the chance of programming on a one's complement machine is rather low.

Comment: To expand on the closing paragraph, even on a "non twos complement CPU" there is no reason to use a representation other than twos complement; whatever operations are used to implement arithmetic on unsigned types inherently work to implement twos complement signed arithmetic as well, and the "native" non-twos-complement signed instructions can just be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, there are 2 possibilities to consider:

- if the bit pattern with all bits set is a trap representation (which is explicitly allowed by the C Standard), passing such a value to the function has undefined behavior.
- if this bit pattern is allowed, it the one's complement representation of *negative zero*, which should compare equal to `0`.  In this case, the function as written will have defined behavior and will return `0` since the initial loop test is false.

The result would be different if the function was written this way:

```
int bitcount32(int x) {
    // naive implementation assuming 31 value bits
    int count = 0, b;
    for (b = 0; b < 31; b++) {
        if (x & (1 << b))
           count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

On this one's complement architecture, `bitcount32(~0)` would evaluate to `31`:

`(x & (1 << b))` with `x` the argument with the specific bit pattern and `b` in range for `1 << b` to be defined, evaluates to `1 << b`, a different value from the result on two's complement and sign/magnitude architectures.

Note however that the posted implementation has undefined behavior for an argument of `INT_MIN` as `x-1` causes a signed arithmetic overflow. It is highly advisable to always use unsigned types for bitwise and shift operations.