# Can xor have UB/IB in C++?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, implementation-defined-behavior

Seeing that the answers to these questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387704/can-bitwise-operators-have-undefined-behavior) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644362/are-the-results-of-bitwise-operations-on-signed-integers-defined)) talk about C, I cannot extend this knowledge to C++, so this is not a duplicate, but a clarification.

Update: I'm only talking about C++. If something is defined in C, it does not mean that it is defined in C++ and vice versa, which is why I am asking this question.

Comment: The other question is tagged C++ and C.  It's not our fault there's no satisfying C++ answer there.  The question **does feel like a duplicate**.  C11 answers are coming just like before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can bitwise operators have undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387704/can-bitwise-operators-have-undefined-behavior)

Comment: What version of C++ are you asking about?  Pretty sure it's well defined behavior in C++20 as signed integers are now guaranteed to be twos-compliment.  Before that. most likely implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @Wyck No, I even listed this link as the first example in my question ...

Comment: @NathanOliver, I will be glad to know about any version, if it is defined in any.

Comment: Well this is the  text from C++20 (acutally the C++23 draft now), and it doesn't appear to me to leave any leeway into what the value could be: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.xor

Comment: I removed the C++ tag from the other questions (they should not be dual tagged, and did not have any C++ answers)

Comment: Those operators are defined on bits. In theory, the only thing implementation defined would be the actual integer value of negative numbers before C++ 20.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Bitwise logic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic), xor can not have UB or IB in results of integer types.

The xor operator performs [usual arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions) on both operands of other types that may lead undefined behavior.

Comment: Sorry for being meticulous, but are there any trap values for the one's complement system that don't support negative zeros in signed integers (as pointed out for C in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46387882))?

Comment: @0dminnimda note that _"...However, all C++ compilers use two's complement representation, and as of C++20, it is the only representation allowed by the standard, ..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types .  Also _"...8-bit one's complement and sign-and-magnitude representations for char have been disallowed since C++11 ..."_ same link